# How to connect flutter app to the Wordpress?

Tags: android, wordpress, rest, flutter

I want to connect my app to Wordpress site 
I want to push and get and change data from my site
How to connect my app to the Wordpress site
I know that, use rest API but I don't know where should I change my code

Answer (score 0):

You could use Flutter WordPress API (flutter_wordpress) it's basically a library that uses WordPress REST API to interact with your WordPress site

You can get more info on [this website](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_wordpress)

Comment: How to use it?
I want to use it
but when I used it
 I have an error